# How to use iterator as parameters method?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have this situation:

```
 void methodB(list<int>::iterator myIt){
    myIt++;
}
void methodA(){
    list<int> * myList=new list<int>();
    list<int>::iterator it=myList->begin();
    //many insertion in myList ...
    methodB(it);
    //...
}
```

I want that, when methodB ends, the iterator is one position forward but I can't do this... if I'm in methodA() and many times call methodB(it), every time the iterator is copied and when the control return to methodA() the **it** variable is **always** in myList->begin().
How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Pass it as a reference? `list<int>::iterator&`

Comment: In this particular instance, use [`std::advance(it, 1)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good model for this is `std::next`, which returns a modified copy of the iterator:

```
list<int>::iterator
methodB(list<int>::iterator myIt){
    myIt++;
    return myIt;
}

void methodA(){
    list<int> * myList=new list<int>();
    list<int>::iterator it=myList->begin();
    //many insertion in myList ...
    it = methodB(it);
    //...
}
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next

Note that container iterators are designed to be cheap to copy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it by reference, like:

```
void methodB(list<int>::iterator& myIt);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be more idiomatic to pass by value and return a new iterator?

Comment: I assume it would be, but following the question logic passing by reference is what the OP wants.